# Ubuntu One failed to sync after password change

Tags: windows, ubuntu-one, client

I have changed my **Ubuntu One** password and now my **Ubuntu One** windows client fails to sync. Is there any way to get the windows client to work again?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and posted a question here: [File sync error (AUTH_FAILED)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419924/file-sync-error-auth-failed-on-windows).

I managed to figure out a fix on my own, but it's not letting me answer my own question yet. :)

There is a program called ubuntu-sso-login-qt that is found in c:\Program Files (x86)\ubuntuone\dist.  I ran that, told it to login with my existing account, then restarted the Ubuntu One control panel.  All is happy again.

Hope this helps.